# Find peak elements (multiple) SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, search, element

how would i find multiple peaks in an array?

given the array: [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,4,2]
i can find the max peak using the code below.

```
func findPeakElement(_ readings: [Int]) -> Int {
   if readings.count == 0 {
      return 0
   }

   while left < right {
      middle1 = (left + right) / 2
      middle2 = middle1 + 1
      if readings[middle1] < readings[middle2] {
         left = middle2
      } else {
         right = middle1
      }
   }         
   return left
}
```

however; i need to find ALL the peaks ;[5,6,4]
what code would i need for this? even if it just told me the number of peaks (3) it would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate your elements and check if your values are ascending or descending and compare your element against the last element. If the current element is greater than the last element mark it as ascending. if it is less and it was ascending mark it as descending and append the last element:

```
func findPeakElement(_ readings: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var ascending = false
    var peaks: [Int] = []
    if var last = readings.first {
        readings.dropFirst().forEach {
            if last < $0 {
                ascending = true
            }
            if $0 < last && ascending  {
                ascending = false
                peaks.append(last)
            }
            last = $0
        }
    }
    return peaks
}
```

---

```
let readings = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,4,2]
let peaks = findPeakElement(readings)
print(peaks)   // [5, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want any value that has a lower value on both sides of it, you can do the following:

```
func findPeaks(readings: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var result = [Int]()
    if readings.count >= 3 {
        for i in 1..<readings.count-1 {
            if readings[i - 1] < readings[i] && readings[i + 1] < readings[i] {
                result.append(readings[i])
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}

let readings = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,4,2]
print(findPeaks(readings: readings))
```

Output:

> [5, 6, 4]

One case this won't handle as-is is something like:

```
[1,4,4,1]
```

This algorithm will not find the `4`. Supporting this will require more work.